# ConTeXt Standalone equivalent to wallpaper package

Tags: context, wallpaper

Using pdflatex, a pdf file was inserted as a full size background,
a letterhead.  An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\begin{document}
\CenterWallPaper{1.0}{background.pdf}
\lipsum[1-14] %dummy text
\end{document}
```

How can this be done using ConTeXt Standalone?

Comment: Related: [How to set a image background and tile on page in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69127/323)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a layer and put it in the page background.

```
\definelayer
  [pagebg]
  [
    x=0mm,
    y=0mm,
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=\paperheight,
  ]

\setlayer
  [pagebg]
  {\externalfigure[dummy][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]}

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background=pagebg]

\starttext

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You could have defined an `overlay` (without defining a `layer`). For example: `\defineoverlay[pagebg][{\externalfigure[dummy][width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]}]` or even `\defineoverlay[pagebg][{\externalfigure[dummy][width=\overlaywidth, height=\overlayheight]}]`

Comment: @Aditya You can use `\overlayfigure{...}` instead of `\externalfigure [...][width=\overla‌​ywidth, height=\overlayheight]` in this case.